# Distinguishing between EditingDidBegin because of user action vs programatic setting

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uicontrol

When I set the text of a UITextField programmatically, the EditingChanged action is not sent to my view controller, the action is only sent when the user changes the text through the keyboard.

However, when I call becomeFirstResponder() on a text field, it does send the EditingDidBegin action. So I can't tell if editing began because the user tapped on the UITextField, or because I did it programmatically. Do you know how I can easily distinguish between the two?

I'm looking for a way to know when the user taps in a UITextField and only when the user taps on it, not when becomeFirstResponder is called on it. Do you know of one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I call `becomeFirstResponder()`

The secret is that when you call `becomeFirstResponder()`, *you* call it. *Your* code is running. *You* are in control. You can do whatever you want.

So if you need your EditingChanged handler to know that you called `becomeFirstResponder()`, you simply have to make a notation of this fact beforehand. For example, you could have a Bool property `justCalledBecomeFirstResponder` which you set to `true` just before calling `becomeFirstResponder()`. Now your EditingChanged handler has only to examine (and possibly reset to `false`) this Bool property before proceeding.

Comment: Such a clever and simple idea. :) I'll delete mine since you beat me by 6 seconds.

Comment: This is what I have now, but I consider it rather inelegant. I was hoping for a more elegant solution. Note that such a bool is not required for EditingChanged.

Comment: @rmaddy Your way of putting it is more elegant and pithy than mine. You should undelete it.

Comment: @DanielT. We live in a world of _events_ bombarding us from the Cocoa framework. We do not get to dictate what they are or when they arrive; we must prepare to receive them and deal with them as reality. This is the standard technique for dealing with this particular reality.